# How to add tabs to JTabbedPane using WindowBuilder

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jtabbedpane, windowbuilder

Ok so I've recently found out about WindowBuilder (Eclipse IDE) that aids in faster creation of Swing applications. I have a added a JTabbedPane using the drag and drop facility. How can I add tabs to it? I have gone through the properties but I couldn't find how to add tabs using WindowBuilder. Although I have manually added tabs but I just want to know what is the other way round.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Just add a `JPanel` to the `JTabbedPane`. The tab will appear. To add more tabs just click the next to the tab header, with the `JPanel` still selected. To switch between tabs just double click the tab header

[image]

Comment: how to use window builder with netbeans?>

Comment: @Developer huh? Not sure your question. Netbeans has GUI Builder and not WindowBuilder. To use GUI Builder in NetBeans just right click on yort project and select `New -> Other -> Swing GUI Forms -> Select a form`

Comment: but i have no options like your GUIbuilder has. like any layout in my guibuilder? so how to add this layout in GUIBuiler?

Comment: In Netbeans is the same: addding panels where the "tabs" captions are. BTW, Love the gif :D

Answer (score -1):

Simple example of JTabbedPane

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;


public class JTabbedPaneDemo extends JFrame
{
JTabbedPane t1=new JTabbedPane();
JPanel p1,p2,p3;
Container c,c1;
JLabel l1,l2,l3;
JTextField text1,text2,text3;
JRadioButton r21,r22,r23;
JCheckBox ch1,ch2,ch3;

public JTabbedPaneDemo() {
      setSize(500,300);
      setVisible(true);

    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    p1=new JPanel();
    p2=new JPanel();
    p3=new JPanel();

    c1=getContentPane();
    p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));

    l1=new JLabel("Name");
    l2=new JLabel("Date of Birth (dd.mm.yyyy)");
    l3=new JLabel("Identification Number");

    text1=new JTextField(10);
    text2=new JTextField(10);
    text3=new JTextField(10);

    p1.add(l1);
    p1.add(text1);
    p1.add(l2);
    p1.add(text2);
    p1.add(l3);
    p1.add(text3);
    c1.add(p1);

    ch1=new JCheckBox("Computers");
    ch2=new JCheckBox("Electronics");
    ch3=new JCheckBox("Marketing");

    r21=new JRadioButton("Graduate");
    r22=new JRadioButton("Post Graduate");
    r23=new JRadioButton("Ph.D");
    ButtonGroup bg=new ButtonGroup();  
    bg.add(r21);
    bg.add(r22);
    bg.add(r23);

    p2.add(r21);
    p2.add(r22);
    p2.add(r23);

    p3.add(ch1);
    p3.add(ch2);
    p3.add(ch3);

    t1.addTab("Personal Information",p1);
    t1.addTab("Education Qualification", p2);
    t1.addTab("Area of intrest",p3);

    add(t1);



}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{



    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new JTabbedPaneDemo();

        }
    });
}
```

}